How can you append multiple data frames to multiple corresponding csv files in R?
I have two dataframes that I have saved to csv:
library(readr)
df1 <-  data.frame(time = c(10,20,30), score = c(4,5,6))
df2 <-  data.frame(lane = c(200,500,400), score = c(2,3,8))
write_csv(df1, "aframe.csv")
write_csv(df2, "bframe.csv")


I am periodically collecting new data that I would like to append to the existing csv files:
df3 <-  data.frame(time = c(11,22,35), score = c(5,4,3))
df4 <-  data.frame(lane = c(700,600,500), score = c(6,7,9))

I can append and write them individually:
write_csv(df3, "aframe.csv", append = TRUE)
write_csv(df4, "bframe.csv", append = TRUE)

How can I do the appending more efficiently, with one code chunk?
I had errors when I tried this:
write_csv(c(df3, df4), c("aframe.csv", "bframe.csv"), append = TRUE)

I am not tied to readr. I had similar problems with write.table.

Can you report the errors? Was the file perhaps open in another application at run time?

You could use purrr's walk2() to iterate through the data frames and csv files:
(walk2 also has an option to include a progress bar with .progress = TRUE.)
library(readr)
library(purrr)

df1 <-  data.frame(time = c(10,20,30), score = c(4,5,6))
df2 <-  data.frame(lane = c(200,500,400), score = c(2,3,8))
write_csv(df1, "aframe.csv")
write_csv(df2, "bframe.csv")

df3 <-  data.frame(time = c(11,22,35), score = c(5,4,3))
df4 <-  data.frame(lane = c(700,600,500), score = c(6,7,9))

walk2(
  list(df3, df4), 
  list("aframe.csv", "bframe.csv"), 
  write_csv, append = TRUE
  )

Created on 2024-05-03 with reprex v2.1.0

Instead of purrr::walk2 like user Carl used, you can use base R Map or mapply.
The data is borrowed from Carl's answer.
library(readr)

df1 <-  data.frame(time = c(10,20,30), score = c(4,5,6))
df2 <-  data.frame(lane = c(200,500,400), score = c(2,3,8))
write_csv(df1, "aframe.csv")
write_csv(df2, "bframe.csv")

df3 <-  data.frame(time = c(11,22,35), score = c(5,4,3))
df4 <-  data.frame(lane = c(700,600,500), score = c(6,7,9))

Map(write_csv, 
    list(df3, df4), 
    list("aframe.csv", "bframe.csv"),
    MoreArgs = list(append = TRUE))

